# Knapp (Basic Algebra) Prop 8.52, error?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The above proposition says:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and let $I$ and $P$ be ideals of $R$ where $P$ is a prime ideal. If $IP=I$, then $I=0$.

I feel that this is false. After passing to localization at $P$ and using Nakayama, we can easily get $S^{-1}I=0$ ($S=R-P$), from which we can conclude that $sI=0$ for some $s\in S$. How can we conclude that $I=0$?

Alternatively, we can use Corollary 2.5 of Atiyah and Macdonald to directly conclude that $xI=0$, where $x=1+p$ with $p\in P$.

The proof given there says since $I$ is a subset of $S^{-1}I$, $I=0$. This is false unless $R$ is a domain, isn't it?

Comment: Corollary 2.5 has another formulation [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/61478/450)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the highlighted proposition  is false  as shown by the following counterexample:
Given a field $k$, take $R=k\times k$  and  $I=P=k\times \{0\}$. Then $IP=I$ and yet $I\neq0$.